# Printer keeps being added automatically

Tags: network, printing

My iMac (Late 2015, Sierra 10.12.2) is under a router connected to a school network, nothing wireless.

Without me actually adding it, tens of the same network printer (HP LaserJet 9050) keeps being automatically added to the system.

I have to periodically delete them before it becomes hundreds.

Does anyone know how this happens and how I can prevent this?